# Why am I getting an error for "favorite" not existing in current context on my switch?

Tags: c#

I am brand new to developing so please forgive me if this is a stupid question.
Here is a snippet of my current project. I get a red squiggly for "favorite" on my switch statement when I use if statements to assign my "favorite" variable based on a users input, but I do not get the red squiggly if I just declare the favorite variable outright. The error says that favorite does not exist in the current context. I apologize if this has been asked before, but I am completely new to this forum as well. Thank you in advance for any light-shedding.

```
 class Program
{
    enum Color  
    {
        Red, Orange, Green, Blue, Indigo, Violet
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string userChoice = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of your favorite color out of the following choices. /n Where 1 = Red /n 2 = Orange /n 3 = Green /n 4 = Blue /n 5 = Indigo /n 6 = Violet");

        if (userChoice == "1")
        {
            Color favorite = Color.Red;
        }
        if (userChoice == "2")
        {
            Color favorite = Color.Orange;
        }
        if (userChoice == "3")
        {
            Color favorite = Color.Green;
        }
        if (userChoice == "4")
        {
            Color favorite = Color.Blue;
        }
        if (userChoice == "5")
        {
            Color favorite = Color.Indigo;
        }
        if (userChoice == "6")
        {
            Color favorite = Color.Violet;
        }

        switch (favorite)
        {
            case Color.Red:
                Console.WriteLine("You chose Red");
                break;
            case Color.Orange:
                Console.WriteLine("You chose Orange");
                break;
            case Color.Green:
                Console.WriteLine("You chose Green");
                break;
            case Color.Blue:
                Console.WriteLine("You chose Blue");
                break;
            case Color.Indigo:
                Console.WriteLine("You chose Indigo");
                break;
            case Color.Violet:
                Console.WriteLine("You chose Violet");
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("You didn't choose a color");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"favorite" is being only created within the scope of each individual "if", and then being 'destroyed'.

```
if (userChoice == "1")           // Here favorite does not exist yet
{
    Color favorite = Color.Red;  // favorite is created and assigned Color.Red
}                                // The scope of "if" ends, so all variables created within are destroyed, in this case, "favorite"
```

So what you really want to do is

```
Color? favorite = null;
if (userChoice == "1")     // Here favorite already exists
{
    favorite = Color.Red;   // favorite is assigned Color.Red
}                           // Same as before, but favorite is not destroyed this time because it was not created(declared) within "if"'s scope
```

On the other hand, you cannot use switch with Color as-is:

> The governing type of a switch statement is established by the switch expression.
>
> > •    If the type of the switch expression is sbyte, byte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, bool, char, string, or an enum-type, or if it is the nullable type corresponding to one of these types, then that is the governing type of the switch statement.
> >
> > •    Otherwise, exactly one user-defined implicit conversion (§6.4) must exist from the type of the switch expression to one of the following possible governing types: sbyte, byte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, char, string, or,  a nullable type corresponding to one of those types.
> >
> > •    Otherwise, if no such implicit conversion exists, or if more than one such implicit conversion exists, a compile-time error occurs.

(From the C# 5.0 specification, 8.7.2 The switch statement - you can find it at ...\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC#\Specifications\1033\CSharp Language Specification.docx)

So here, assuming you're just toying a bit with the if and switch statements, the end result would be more along the lines of

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of your favorite color out of the following choices. \n Where 1 = Red \n 2 = Orange \n 3 = Green \n 4 = Blue \n 5 = Indigo \n 6 = Violet");
    string userChoice = Console.ReadLine();

    Color? favorite = null;

    if (userChoice == "1")
    {
        favorite = Color.Red;
    }
    if (userChoice == "2")
    {
        favorite = Color.Orange;
    }
    if (userChoice == "3")
    {
        favorite = Color.Green;
    }
    if (userChoice == "4")
    {
        favorite = Color.Blue;
    }
    if (userChoice == "5")
    {
        favorite = Color.Indigo;
    }
    if (userChoice == "6")
    {
        favorite = Color.Violet;
    }

    switch (userChoice)
    {
        case "1":
            Console.WriteLine("You chose Red");
            break;
        case "2":
            Console.WriteLine("You chose Orange");
            break;
        case "3":
            Console.WriteLine("You chose Green");
            break;
        case "4":
            Console.WriteLine("You chose Blue");
            break;
        case "5":
            Console.WriteLine("You chose Indigo");
            break;
        case "6":
            Console.WriteLine("You chose Violet");
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("You didn't choose a color");
            break;
    }

    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why am I getting an error for “favorite” not existing in current
>   context on my switch?

Because you have declared `favorite` as a local variable in the body of your `if` statements. This means that the variable `favorite` is not accessible out of these bodies.

> How we could fix this?

I would try the following (There are also other options):

```
// Here we make use of a nullable.
// since the user hasn't enter any color yet the value of color is null.  
Color? color = null;

// Here we ask the user to enter his choice.
string userChoice = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of your favorite color out of the following choices. /n Where 1 = Red /n 2 = Orange /n 3 = Green /n 4 = Blue /n 5 = Indigo /n 6 = Violet");

// According to users input, we set the corresponding color.
// If not a correct color entered, then the value of color would stay null.
if (userChoice == "1")
{
    color = Color.Red;
}
if (userChoice == "2")
{
    color = Color.Green;
}
if (userChoice == "3")
{
    color = Color.Blue;
}
if (userChoice == "4")
{
    color = Color.Blue;
}

switch (color)
{
    case Color.Red:
        Console.WriteLine("You chose Red");
        break;
    case Color.Green:
        Console.WriteLine("You chose Green");
        break;
    case Color.Blue:
        Console.WriteLine("You chose Blue");
        break;
    case Color.Orange:
        Console.WriteLine("You chose Orange");
        break;
    case null:
        Console.WriteLine("You didn't choose a color");
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("You didn't choose a color");
        break;
}
```

Comment: OK, thank you for quick response. I tried to define the "favorite" variable outside of the if statements and get a different error that says: A local variable named "favorite" cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning meaning to 'favorite', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else.

Comment: I don't see your code. But if you have do this: `Color favorite;` outside if statements and then in each `if`'s statement code block have this `Color favorite = Color.Red;`, this is an error. You can't define two variables with the same name. On the other hand, if you try my answer, you will see it works.

Comment: What I am trying to do is use the colors I defined in my Color enum. The solution you provided eliminates the enum. I still want to use the enum.

Comment: I eliminated the `enum`, in order to copy and paste all your code. Of course you will use your enum and you will add both the if and switch statements that aren't in mine. Furthermore, I renamed `favoriteColor` to `color`. Apparently, you can change also this.

Comment: Ah, I see said the blind man! Thank you Christos for your patience. I realize there are probably much better ways to accomplish the same task but I was trying to better understand the relationship between enums and switches. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You define "favorite" variable in "if" body, then you're using "switch" on "favorite" variable. But let's think what's happen if noone "if" body fires? - Correct, "favorite" variable will not be defined, but it's in use in "switch" statement - logical mistake. That's why compiler prevents you from this mistake. Just define "favorite" variable out of "if" body and then assign necessary value to it in "if" body

Comment: OK, thank you for quick response. I tried to define the "favorite" variable outside of the if statements and get a different error that says:  A local variable named "favorite" cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning meaning to 'favorite', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else.

Comment: @NewbMilo please see my answer and let me know if it is clear to your or not. Thanks